# SSIS.ReplacementTask after upgrading VS2019 to VS2022

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-data-tools

We have upgraded from VS2019 to VS2022.
We have hundreds of packages, tested a lot of them.
One of the older ones now does not open.
When opening a package in this solution we first get three errors referring to the connections 'Unable to create the type with the name OLEDB'.
This concerns 2 MSQSQL drivers and one Sybase Anywhere driver. In the .conmgr files I see no difference with other working conn managers.
After these three errors the package further opens and all tasks are shown as SSIS.ReplacementTask.

Below you see the xml of such a task before and after opening the package. The package was created in 2019 using VS2012.

I only found this post which seems to describe the problem. However, we are using the actual versions of both VS2022 en the SSDT, not any beta releases.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1188117/errors-upgrading-ssis-2014-packages-to-2022-using

Is there a way to solve this without reverting to an older version of Visual Studio / SSDT?

BEFORE:

<DTS:Executable
DTS:refId="Package\Truncate the table"
DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask.ExecuteSQLTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
DTS:Description="Execute SQL Task"
DTS:DTSID="{e9f3593b-2212-46c1-9390-259186485c23}"
DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask.ExecuteSQLTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
DTS:LocaleID="-1"
DTS:ObjectName="Truncate the table"
DTS:ThreadHint="0">
<DTS:Variables />
DTS:ObjectData
<SQLTask:SqlTaskData
SQLTask:Connection="{DD6263AC-CC36-4A31-A57A-ECE18694CBEF}"
SQLTask:SqlStatementSource="TRUNCATE TABLE [table1]
" xmlns:SQLTask="www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask" />
</DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:Executable>

AFTER

<DTS:Executable
DTS:refId="Package\Truncate the table"
DTS:CreationName="SSIS.ReplacementTask"
DTS:DTSID="{e9f3593b-2212-46c1-9390-259186485c23}"
DTS:ExecutableType="SSIS.ReplacementTask"
DTS:LocaleID="-1"
DTS:ObjectName="Truncate the table">
<DTS:Variables />
DTS:ObjectData
<SQLTask:SqlTaskData
SQLTask:Connection="{DD6263AC-CC36-4A31-A57A-ECE18694CBEF}"
SQLTask:SqlStatementSource="TRUNCATE TABLE [Table1]
" xmlns:SQLTask="www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask" />
</DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:Executable>